# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express - Importing encrypted database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have a file of database that I want to import into my SQL Server 2012 Express.

I tried importing options but I always get undefined file.

click run to see the image

```html
    <image src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iybvx.png" width="800"  />
```

Comment: The screenshot isn't viewable - can you try to upload to some other site and re-add the link?

Comment: this the file I'm trying to import